# Kafa + Structured Streaming : Read from topics in parallel

Tags: apache-kafka, real-time, batch-processing, spark-structured-streaming

I'm building a real-time data pipeline with the below flow

```
Source --> Kafka --> Structured Streaming (2.3) --> Sink
```

In doing so, I read from 3 topics.

```
Topic 1: sample_t1 (weekly) (written to Sink_Weekly) 
Topic 2: sample_t2 (once a day) (written to Sink_Daily)
Topic 3: sample_t3 (hourly) (Join with Sink_Daily and update Sink_Daily)
```

**TL;DR**

### Current Approach:

At the moment, I'm reading all the topics as shown below with the intent that "no matter when data arrives, I will be ready to process it.. no matter which topic it is coming from".

```
 df = spark 
        .readStream 
        .format("kafka") 
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") 
        .option("subscribePattern", "sample.*") 
        .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
        .load()

query = df.writeStream
    .format("console")
    .foreach(new JoinWithSink(connection)) // Logic to perform joins as I get in the data
    .option("checkpointLocation", path/to/checkpoint/dir)
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

But this approach got me thinking if this is the most optimal approach to handle topics with different frequencies.

### Alternate Solution:

Another solution I have is to read each topic as a separate streaming query and then use stream-stream join to carry out the use case

```
df_weekly = spark 
        .readStream 
        .format("kafka") 
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") 
        .option("subscribe", "sample_t1") 
        .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
        .load()


 df_daily = spark 
        .readStream 
        .format("kafka") 
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") 
        .option("subscribe", "sample_t2") 
        .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
        .load()

 df_hourly = spark 
        .readStream 
        .format("kafka") 
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") 
        .option("subscribe", "sample_t3") 
        .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
        .load()
```

### Use Case:

I want to be able to perform joins/lookup on the faster streaming query (Topic1) and update the sink accordingly.

### Questions:

1. Is it better to use subscribePattern and read all topics at once or is it better to split the topics into different streaming queries?
2. How do I run multiple streaming queries in parallel? use case: run joins between topic1 and topic2 in parallel with joins between topic1 and topic3?
3. In case of failure, how do I restart the streaming query by ignoring the corrupt record?
4. Stop and restart the streaming query after x hours programmatically? I know I can add Triggers or use cron on a wrapper script.. is there a better way to stops and re-start the query?

Please let me know if you need more details, I will be happy to provide any additional detais.

Comment: Why do you want to stop and re-start streaming jobs after x hours? If you do not want to have them running 24/7, would it not be easier to have batch joins?

Comment: @mike: I have seen in the past that the streams were hogging up memory for which we had to restart our streaming jobs once a day (this was with Spark Streaming - Spark 1.4.1).. We should've optimized our code but instead, we resorted to restarting the jobs.. not the most ideal way but it got our job done.

Comment: Understood. The reason behind the growing memory could be that the jobs keeps unlimited state in the join (without using watermarks)...? This question is overall very broad and although I have some ideas I find it hard to answer it. It also seems that you are working with many work arounds and am not sure about the actual use case behind it. Would it be possible to narrow this question?

Comment: @mike: Sure.. we can ignore #4 for now.. As the questions are in order of priority. Unfortunately, watermarking was not available in 1.4.1.